# can see the container with docker ps, but not actually working

Tags: docker

I got stuck in docker. plz help me..

I just made really simple express server (port=3000) and dockerfile (expose 3000)

I did successfully run the image and I could see the running process with 'docker ps'.
But, when I sent any request like just typed the 'localhost:3000', it didn't work.

How can i solve this problem?..

(I typed docker run -d -p 80:3000  for running image)

(when i was in the container with 'docker exec' and ran 'npm start', express server occured 'listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use' error.
so I don't think i connect wrong port)

Comment: You have mapped port **80** of your host system with docker. so your website will accessible by **localhost** only (no need to specify port)

Comment: are you running docker via docker toolbox?

Comment: yes. I'm using docker toolbox because my window is not pro

Comment: The problem is I just use localhost... Thank you for your comment. It reminded me!

Answer (score 0):

For binding local port 3000 to docker container use - `run -d -p 3000:3000 <image_name>`.

Comment: This was not in my case, but I really appreciate your comment!

Comment: @hkseo So what exactly was the problem, because I cannot understand it from your comments under the post.As I saw it, you typed  'localhost:3000' sending request and didn't got anything because you started container on port 80.

Comment: actually I'm using docker toolbox that use virtaul address like 192.xxx.xxx.xxx. So, I need to request to 192.xxx.:80 instead of localhost:80. It worked well for me.

Comment: @hkseo Ok, but you haven't mentioned anything about docker toolbox, in your post.